Boundaries gap in a zoomable 2d map
I'm rendering an interactive 2d map with pygame.
My idea is to exract the coordinates of each regions from a png and use them to scroll and zoom with the following algorithm:
x - offset[0] * zoom, y - offset[1] * zoom
however, after a few degrees of zoom, a small gap is created between the borders of the various regions. Is there a way to reduce it?

def zoom_point(point, offset, zoom):
    x = int((point[0] - offset[0]) * zoom)
    y = int((point[1] - offset[1]) * zoom)
    return x, y


def zoomed_points(points, offset, zoom):
    for point in points:
        yield zoom_point(point, offset, zoom)


For zooming wouldn't you have to scale the image?
Also the zooming code only moves the x and y not actually zooming it, for zooming blit the image onto a second surface and scale it, then blit it onto the window.
